# How to get a (singleton) Reference of an EntityListener instance

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

(Spring-Data-)JPA automatically instantiates EntityListeners for Entity classes annotated with @EntityListeners(EntityListenerClass.class). I need to access these automatically instantiated EntityListeners from elsewhere as well, i.e. I need to call methods on them from a "Controller" object. That's why I'd like to obtain an additional reference to a particular EntityListener instance from that controller.

For example consider an Entity,

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(EntLi.class)
public class MyEntity {
    ...
}
```

an EntityListener,

```
@Service
public class EntLi {
    public EntLi(){
        System.out.printf("EntLi instanciated %s\n", this);
        new Exception().printStackTrace();
    }
    ...
}
```

a CRUD repository,

```
public interface MyEntRepo extends CrudRepository<MyEntity, MyEntKeyType> {

}
```

and a controller that uses it all (and needs a Reference to the `EntLi`-instance created via `@EntityListeners(EntLi.class)`)

```
public class Ctrl{

    @Autowired
    private MyEntRepo repo;
    
    @Autowired
    private EntLi listener;

    ...
}
```

Why are two different instances of `EntLi` created and what's the correct way to get hold of the EntLi instance (Reference) originally created by the Spring Data JPA when `MyEntRepo` got instantiated?

Answer (score 0):

That is "be design" (IMO, poor design):

whether `SpringBeanContainer#getBean` creates brand new bean instance or uses exisiting one [depends on](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/dc5bef16b40baf6e27e66a8d1696b1474335f8c6/spring-orm/src/main/java/org/springframework/orm/hibernate5/SpringBeanContainer.java#L146) result of `BeanContainer.LifecycleOptions#useJpaCompliantCreation` method, which in turn always returns true:

```java
if (lifecycleOptions.useJpaCompliantCreation()) {
    return new SpringContainedBean<>(
        this.beanFactory.createBean(beanType),
        this.beanFactory::destroyBean);
}
else {
    return new SpringContainedBean<>(this.beanFactory.getBean(beanType));
}
```

The option is to delegate listener calls to another spring service/component (preferably `@Lazy`), in that case you will able to share the same instance across persistence context and application.